# UPDATE table record instead of adding a new record MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ok .. Here is the thing. I want to list users logged on and change their status when logged out. This works perfect. I created a table for that called tblaudit_users. The existing users I SELECT from a tbl_users table.

What I want, is that if an user already exists in the tblaudit_users table it will UPDATE the LastTimeSeen time with NOW(). But instead of updating that record, it creates a new record. This way the table will grow and grow and I want to avoid that. The code I use for this looks like:

+++++++++++++++++++

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $achternaam = $_SESSION['achternaam'];
    $district = $_SESSION['district'];
    $gemeente = $_SESSION['gemeente'];

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblaudit_users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND active = '1' LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute();

    foreach($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $value){
        $duplicate = $value->username;  
    }

    if($duplicate != 1){

        $insert = $db->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO tblaudit_users (user_id, username, achternaam, district, gemeente, ipaddress, LastTimeSeen, status)
                    VALUES ('{$userId}', '{$username}', '{$achternaam}', '{$district}', '{$gemeente}', '{$ipaddress}', NOW(), '1')
                    ");
        $insert->execute();

    } elseif($duplicate = 1){

        $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE tblaudit_users SET LastTimeSeen = NOW(),status = '1' WHERE username = '{$username}'");
        $update->execute();

    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }
}
```

I am lost and searched many websites/pages to solve this so hopefully someone here can help me? Thanks in advance !!

UPDATE:

I've tried the below with no result.

+++++

```
$insert = $db->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO tblaudit_users (user_id, username, achternaam, district, gemeente, ipaddress, LastTimeSeen, status)
                    VALUES ('{$userId}', '{$username}', '{$achternaam}', '{$district}', '{$gemeente}', '{$ipaddress}', NOW(), '1')
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set LastTimeSeen = NOW(), status = '1'
                    ");
        $insert->execute();
```

Ok. I altered my query and code a little:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblaudit_users WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
$query->execute();

if($query){

    $insert = $db->prepare("
                INSERT INTO tblaudit_users (user_id, username, achternaam, district, gemeente, ipaddress, LastTimeSeen, status)
                VALUES ('{$userId}', '{$username}', '{$achternaam}', '{$district}', '{$gemeente}', '{$ipaddress}', NOW(), '1')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set LastTimeSeen = NOW(), status = '1'
                ");
    $insert->execute();

} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
```

}

I also added a UNIQUE key called pid (primary id). Still not working.

Comment: Have you tried the MySQL statement syntax `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? If not, try it. If so, please [edit] your question to show what you've tried

Comment: @David: I already tried that but it doesn't work. Also deleted some WHERE clausule from the $query. WHERE active='1' is not a column in the table.

Comment: Does `tblaudit_users` have a primary/unique key?

Comment: It seems that it can't find a record with the $username. My guess is that my 'if' statement is wrong, but can't figure out why

Comment: And userid is set as a key?

Comment: user_id comes from another table called tbl_users. There it is a primary key.

Comment: That is not what is needed. If you want to avoid that the `tblaudit_users table` grows with multiple records for user, you must make `user_id` also a unique key in that table. And then you might consider to just move the audit columns into the `tbl_users` table. You need to think this through: either you want one record per user, and then: why not put it in the users table? **OR** you want multiple records per user, giving you a history of the accesses made per user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){

    $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $achternaam = $_SESSION['achternaam'];
    $district = $_SESSION['district'];
    $gemeente = $_SESSION['gemeente'];

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblaudit_users WHERE user_id = '{$userId}' LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute();

    if($query->rowcount()<1){

      $insert = $db->prepare("
                  INSERT INTO tblaudit_users (user_id, username, achternaam, district, gemeente, ipaddress, LastTimeSeen, status)
                  VALUES ('{$userId}', '{$username}', '{$achternaam}', '{$district}', '{$gemeente}', '{$ipaddress}', NOW(), '1')
                  ");
      $insert->execute();

    } elseif($query->rowcount()>0) {

        $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE tblaudit_users SET LastTimeSeen = NOW(),status = '1' WHERE user_id = '{$userId}'");
        $update->execute(); 

    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }
}
```

Instead of using $username in my query, I choose $userId and it works.

Comment: You're still vulnerable to SQL injection, and your code will one day fail if two users execute this script at the same time (concurrency).

Comment: @trincot: Can you explain me where the code in vulnerable to SQL injection and why it will fail if two users execute this script? Thanks

Comment: Where you insert session variables like `gemeente` right into the`INSERT` statement. Since they are at some point defined by users, they could contain malicious code, which would alter the meaning of the SQL statement. Read about SQL injection. If two users execute the script at almost the same time, and both have the same user id in their session (for instance if I use two browser windows), then both could get no records from the first `SELECT`, and then insert both a record with the same user_id value, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Base on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, don't use 'set' in update syntax

example from the page:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=9;
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- You test on `$query`, but that is your statement object, which also will be valid even if you have no records returned from the `select` statement;
- There can be issues accessing a second prepared statement before making sure the previous one is closed or at least has all its records fetched;
- There is a syntax error in the `insert` statement (`set` should not be there);
- For the `insert ... on duplicate key update` to work, the values you provide must include the unique key;
- SQL injection vulnerability;
- Unnecessary split of `select` and `insert`: this can be done in one statement

You can write your test using [`num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php). To get a correct count call [`store_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php). Also it is good practice to close a statement before issuing the next one:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblaudit_users 
                       WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1");
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
if($query->num_rows()){
     $query->close();
     // etc...
```

However, this whole query is unnecessary when you do `insert ... on duplicate key update`: there is no need to first check with a `select` whether that user actually exists. That is all done by the `insert ... on duplicate key update` statement.

#### Error in `INSERT`

The syntax for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should not have the word `SET` following it.

#### Prevent SQL Injection

Although you use prepared statements (good!), you still inject strings into your SQL statements (bad!). One of the advantages of prepared statements is that you can use arguments to your query without actually injecting strings into the SQL string, using [`bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
$insert = $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO tblaudit_users (user_id, username, achternaam, district, 
                                gemeente, ipaddress, LastTimeSeen, status)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW(), '1')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE LastTimeSeen = NOW(), status = '1'
    ");
$insert->bind_param("ssssss", $userId, $username, $achternaam, 
                              $district, $gemeente, $ipaddress);
$insert->execute();
```

This way you avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Make sure that `user_id` has a unique constraint in the `tblaudit_users`. It does not help to have another (auto_increment) field as primary key. It must be one of the fields you are inserting values for.

The above code no longer uses `$query`. You don't need it.